# Is there a name for this type of bug where a bool is overwritten on every iteration of a loop giving an invalid result?

Tags: bug-report, terminology

I have found several instances of bugs like this in dusty corners of our automation code base. Fortunately the person responsible for snippets like these has no longer with the company, but I'd like to warn my coworkers to watch out for it in code reviews.

```
var NumberList = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 11, 4, 5, 6, 7};
bool AllNumbersLessThanTen = true;
foreach (var number in NumberList)
{
    if (number >= 10)
        AllNumbersLessThanTen = false;
    else
        AllNumbersLessThanTen = true;
}
```

In the above snippet `AllNumbersLessThanTen` is set to true at the end of the loop because on the last iteration since `7 >= 10` evaluates to false we go to the else statement which assigns `AllNumbersLessThanTen`, even though 11 is obviously not less than ten. The resulting boolean flag is invalid. The obvious fix is to delete the `else` and associated code block.

Is there a common name or way to describe this type of bug in QA or software development parlance I could use when writing or discussing bugs of this nature?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's enough to call it a logic error.

> In computer programming, a logic error is a bug in a program that causes it to operate incorrectly, but not to terminate abnormally (or crash). A logic error produces unintended or undesired output or other behaviour, although it may not immediately be recognized as such.

Text above taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error